# method post, put, delete route not work on laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I try test api rest on laravel 5 but I have problems with method post, put, delete.
In my **route.php** file I have code:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function()
    {
        Route::get('', ['uses' => 'UserController@allUsers']);

        Route::get('{id}', ['uses' => 'UserController@getUser']);

        Route::post('', ['uses' => 'UserController@saveUser']);

        Route::put('{id}', ['uses' => 'UsercCntroller@updateUser']);

        Route::delete('{id}', ['uses' => 'UserController@deleteUsers']);

    });
});

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return 'Enjoy the test...';
});
```

and in **UserController.php** have code:

```
public function allUsers()
{
   return 'test';
}

public function getUser($id)
{
    return 'test get user';
}

public function saveUser()
{
    return 'test save user';
}

public function updateUser($id)
{
    return 'test update user';
}

public function deleteUsers($id)
{
    return 'test delete user';
}
```

When I run with method get it works good but with method post, put and delete it does not work.
Why is this?

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour))

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make REST APIs then use laravel's generators.

Use `php artisan make:controller UserController`

Laravel automatically creates RESTful controller class for you with all required methods.

Then just put one line in your `routes.php`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route:resource('user', 'UserController');
});
```

And that's it, now you can access get, post, put, and delete requests very easily.

If you want to see what route I should use for what method then simply fire `php artisan route:list` from commandline.

And because of laravel comes with built in csrf token verification middleware, you must have to pass `_token` with your post data request. Or either you can access those routes without csrf token verification by doing this:

Go to `kernel.php` in Http folder under the app directory, and comment the csrfToken line.

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
 // 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];
```

Comment: thanks for your support, i do follow your show but it still not work. please explain more detail. thanks

Comment: thanks. i use route post or delete method to usercontroller.php on laravel 5 when test it show error TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 2440:

Comment: It's because csrf middleware is enabled by default in laravel, you can disable it from kernel.php in Http folder.

Comment: With Laravel 5.3 there is clear separation between **"web routes"** (with session handling, CSRF required...) and **"API routes"** ("stateless", no CSRF required... and with a default `/api` prefix). Web routes must be defined in `routes/web.php` and API routes in `routes/api.php`